# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_value'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using the `set_value`() function but now it says it's deprecated.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60294463/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-set-value) said to use `.at` instead. I tried this but it does not work for me.

```py
for i in range(0,len(text)):
    clean=cleaner.clean(str(text[i]))
        
    df.set_value(i, 'clean', clean)

    try:

        #translated_tweet=translator.translate(clean).text
        translated_tweet= translator.translate(clean).text
        df.set_value(i, 'translated', translated_tweet)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        continue
    textB = Analyzer(translated_tweet)
    score = textB.polarity
    df.set_value(i, 'score', score)


    if score <0.00:
        atrb = 'Neg'
        df.set_value(i, 'atrb', atrb )

    elif score >0.00:
        atrb = 'Poz'
        df.set_value(i, 'atrb', atrb )

    else:
        atrb = 'Notr'
        df.set_value(i, 'atrb', atrb )
```

How can I convert this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use ".at" like this:
df.at["YOURINDEX", "YOURCOLUMN"] = "YOURVALUE"
so in your example the score code-snippet would look like this:

```
df.at[i, 'score'] = score
```

Alternatively you should also be able to use .loc[] like this:

```
df.loc[i, 'score'] = score
```